# Scala generating time series data using external val

Tags: scala, time-series, java-time

I try to generate a Array/List of data from a start_time, so my code is

```
var temp = parse_time

// for (i <- 1 to 10) yield temp.plusSeconds(600) // method 1

val max = 10
Range (0, max).map( _ => (temp.plusSeconds(600))) // method 2
```

Both method will yield same result with the data inside the Array without any incremental change.

Could anyone help me figure out why and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate the next entry from the previous one (starting with `temp`), try `List.iterate`:

```
List.iterate(temp, max)(_.plusSeconds(600))
```

---

Here is what it does for integers:

```
List.iterate(42, 10)(_ + 600)
```

produces:

```
List(42, 642, 1242, 1842, 2442, 3042, 3642, 4242, 4842, 5442)
```

---

Here is another example with `java.time.LocalDateTime`:

```
List.iterate(LocalDateTime.now(), 10)(_.plusSeconds(600)) foreach println
```

Output:

```
2018-06-27T12:52:53.237
2018-06-27T13:02:53.237
2018-06-27T13:12:53.237
2018-06-27T13:22:53.237
2018-06-27T13:32:53.237
2018-06-27T13:42:53.237
2018-06-27T13:52:53.237
2018-06-27T14:02:53.237
2018-06-27T14:12:53.237
2018-06-27T14:22:53.237
```

Comment: Hi, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
List.tabulate(max)(i => temp.plusSeconds(600 * i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `.plusSeconds` yields a new value instead of mutating the original value you get all the results plussed with 600.

Here's example `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`

```
scala> import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalDateTime

scala> val temp = LocalDateTime.now
temp: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2018-06-26T17:31:36.858

scala> Range (0, 10).map( _ => (temp.plusSeconds(600)))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[java.time.LocalDateTime] = Vector(
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858, 
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858, 
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858, 
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858, 
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858, 
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858, 
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858, 
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858, 
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858, 
     2018-06-26T17:41:36.858)
```

**If you want incremental `.plusSeconds` use can use accumulator pattern,**

```
scala>     def add(start: Int, end: Int, date: LocalDateTime, dates: List[LocalDateTime]): List[LocalDateTime] = {
     |       if (  start == end ) dates
     |       else {
     |         val newDate = date.plusSeconds(600)
     |         add(start + 1, end, newDate, dates :+ newDate)
     |       }
     |     }
add: (start: Int, end: Int, date: java.time.LocalDateTime, dates: List[java.time.LocalDateTime])List[java.time.LocalDateTime]

scala> add(0, 10, LocalDateTime.now(), List.empty)
res19: List[java.time.LocalDateTime] = List(
2018-06-26T18:10:23.055, 
2018-06-26T18:20:23.055, 
2018-06-26T18:30:23.055, 
2018-06-26T18:40:23.055, 
2018-06-26T18:50:23.055, 
2018-06-26T19:00:23.055, 
2018-06-26T19:10:23.055, 
2018-06-26T19:20:23.055, 
2018-06-26T19:30:23.055, 
2018-06-26T19:40:23.055)
```

Or you can use `List.iterate` which is basically using the mutable accumulator pattern as well.

```
  def iterate[A](start: A, len: Int)(f: A => A): CC[A] = {
    val b = newBuilder[A]
    if (len > 0) {
      b.sizeHint(len)
      var acc = start
      var i = 1
      b += acc

      while (i < len) {
        acc = f(acc)
        i += 1
        b += acc
      }
    }
    b.result()
  }
```